# HTTPMetadataProvider through proxy

Tags: spring-security

Good Morning,

I use the spring security saml extension, and I need to retrieve the IDP metadata through proxy.
Is there a way and an example to pass the httpproxy to HTTPMetadataProvider in the securityContext.xml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any answer for this?? I want to know the same thing!